# Por que utilizar DriverManager para conexão com banco?

Tags: java, banco-de-dados

Estou me conectando no banco de dados SQLite com o seguinte código:

```
public SQLiteConnection conn() throws SQLException{
        String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
      try {
       return new SQLiteConnection(path, "DadosPastas.s3db");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Porém observei vários exemplos da seguinte forma:

```
 import java.sql.*;

 public class SQLiteJDBC {
 public static void main( String args[] ) {
  Connection c = null;

  try {
     Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
     c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
  } catch ( Exception e ) {
     System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
     System.exit(0);
  }
  System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
 }
}
```

Já pesquisei e não encontrei a resposta de, por que usar o `DriverManager` como no exemplo acima.

Então, por que utilizar o `DriverManager` dessa maneira especificamente?

***EDIT***

[Link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/215642/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-usar-sqliteconnection-e-drivermanager-java) para a pergunta: Diferença entre usar SQLiteConnection e DriverManager Java

Comment: Sua pergunta é : "Porque usar o `DriverManager`"? Essa é sua dúvida?!

Comment: Sim. Vou colocar na pergunda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entre as diversas interfaces do pacote `java.sql`, referindo ao JDBC, existe a interface `Connection` que define métodos para executar uma *query*, comitar transação e fechar a conexão, entre outros recursos. Para trabalhar como por exemplo o MySQL, é necessário a utilização de classes concretas que implementem essas interfaces do pacote `java.sql`.

Esse conjunto de classes concretas é quem fará a ponte entre o código cliente que usa a API JDBC e o banco de dados. São essas classes que sabem se comunicar através do protocolo proprietário do banco de dados. Esse conjunto de classes recebe o nome de *driver*.

Quando de fato queres abrir uma conexão com um banco de dados, é necessário utilizar sempre um *driver*. A classe [`DriverManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) é a responsável por se comunicar com todos os *drivers* que que é deixado disponível. Para isso, é invocado o método estático `getConnection` com uma *string* que indica a qual banco deseja conectar. Como você fez na pergunta:

```
c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
```

O método possui três sobrecargas:

```
public static Connection getConnection(String url)
public static Connection getConnection(String url, Properties info)
public static Connection getConnection(String url, String user, String password)
```

Referências

- [Bancos de dados e JDBC](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-java-web/bancos-de-dados-e-jdbc/)
- [Classe de conexão em Java](http://www.devmedia.com.br/classe-de-conexao-em-java-no-netbeans-driver-mysql/18804)

Comment: Obrigado acklay. Se eu usar o `SQLiteConnection` sem o `DriverManager` tem alguma problema técnico ou de desempenho?

Comment: @Robss70 desculpe-me, pra te falar a verdade, não sei nem se é possível.

Comment: No código da pergunta está sem, e no debug aparece a conexão aberta normalmente. Não acho a resposta em lugar nem um, por que todo mundo usa esse drivermanager.

Comment: @Robss70 o que daria pra fazer então, seria um experimento, medindo o tempo de execução usando as duas classes. Através de vários testes, da pra tomar uma decisão. Vou dar mais uma olhada se encontro alguma coisa em relação a isso e te falo.

Comment: Se você achar alguma coisa fico muito agradecido, já não sei mais onde procurar. Vou fazer os testes.

Comment: @Robss70 bom, a na resposta eu foquei em "porque usar DriverManager", por isso dei essa resposta, descrevendo seu funcionamento. Talvez então, seria melhor uma pergunta focando mais na "Diferença entre usar SQLiteConnection e DriverManager em questão de performance".

Comment: Você tem razão. Vou marcar como resposta e fazer outra pergunta