# Diferença entre usar SQLiteConnection e DriverManager Java

Tags: java, banco-de-dados

Estou conectando no banco de dados Sqlite com o seguinte código:

```
 import org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection;


 public SQLiteConnection conn() throws SQLException{
    String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");
  try {
   return new SQLiteConnection(path, "DadosPastas.s3db");
 } catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
 }
}
```

Quando faço um debug na IDE o resultado é que a conexão foi estabelecida com sucesso.

Porem observei vários exemplos da seguinte forma:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class SQLiteJDBC {
public static void main( String args[] ) {
Connection c = null;

try {
 Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
 c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
} catch ( Exception e ) {
 System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
 System.exit(0);
}
 System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
 }
}
```

Minha dúvida é qual a diferença em aspectos técnicos e de performance entre usar o SQLiteConnection diretamente ou usar o DriverManager.

[Link](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) para a biblioteca do Sqlite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não sei o que você quer dizer com "aspectos técnicos", mas em relação a performance, é notório que JDBC é mais rápido. Fiz um algoritmo para testarmos:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection;

public class SQLiteConnTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long startTime, endTime;
        double duration;

        File path = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        System.out.println("Conexao com SQLiteConnection...");

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        sqliteConnection(path);
        endTime = System.nanoTime();

        duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000d;

        System.out.println("Tempo(ms): " + String.format("%.3f", duration));

        System.out.println("Conexao com JDBC...");

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        jdbcConnection(path);
        endTime = System.nanoTime();

        duration = (endTime - startTime) / 1000000d;

        System.out.println("Tempo(ms): " + String.format("%.3f", duration));

    }

    public static void sqliteConnection(File path) {

        try {
            SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(path.getAbsolutePath(), "DadosPastas.s3db");
            System.out.println("SQLiteConnection has opened");
            conn.close();
            System.out.println("SQLiteConnection has closed");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void jdbcConnection(File path) {

        try {

            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + path + "/test.db");
            System.out.println("JDBC Connection has opened");
            c.close();
            System.out.println("JDBC Connection has closed");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

No teste, eu calculo o tempo em que ambas as formas levam para abrir e fechar a conexão em seguida.

No primeiro teste, executei sem nenhum dos bancos estarem criados, para ver se o fato de ter que criá-lo influi no tempo. A saida foi:

```
Conexao com SQLiteConnection...
SQLiteConnection has opened
SQLiteConnection has closed
Tempo(ms): 227,829
Conexao com JDBC...
JDBC Connection has opened
JDBC Connection has closed
Tempo(ms): 3,559
```

Uma vez com os bancos criados, executei novamente:

```
Conexao com SQLiteConnection...
SQLiteConnection has opened
SQLiteConnection has closed
Tempo(ms): 249,077
Conexao com JDBC...
JDBC Connection has opened
JDBC Connection has closed
Tempo(ms): 3,039
```

Percebe-se que é grande a diferença de tempo entre ambos, sendo o JDBC bem mais performático que a classe `SQLiteConnection`. Isso se deve ao jdbc ser nativo, o que vai fazer ele quase sempre ser mais rápido.

Eu não sei onde você encontrou essa forma de conectar com esta classe, mas até a propria documentação do driver sugere [utilizar o DriverManager](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc#markdown-header-usage), e não fala nada a respeito desta forma que você testou.

Comment: Eu não encontrei, fui fazendo testes chegar nisso ai. Só me tira uma última dúvida, Para a conexão com o banco ficaria assim "Aplicação" --> JDBC --> Driver do Banco --> Banco. É isto?

Comment: @Robss70 não entendi sua duvida. A conexao é do jeito que você vinha fazendo mesmo, na classe `SQLiteJDBC`

Comment: Eu não entendi bem para que server esse JDBC. Eu já li bastante a respeito, sei que é uma API e tal, porem não entendi qual o papel do JDBC e o driver proprio do banco de dados. Quanto a performance sua resposta matou minha dúvida.

Comment: @Robss70 entenda o JDBC  como uma especificação que define como o java faz transações e conexões com banco de dados, independente qual seja. Todo banco de dados que fornece um driver, geralmente segue essa especificação, e é isso que facilita nossa vida, afinal, você só tem que se preocupar em criar instruções SQL.